# laravel queue:listen timeout setting not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm creating a web that can parse excel file using Laravel queue. The web will push a bash command into the queue, and the queue just have to run that shell command in the server to parse the excel file.
This is my command for running the queue:

```
php /var/www/html/artisan queue:listen --timeout=600 --memory=2048
```

The queue works, and the memory setting gets transferred into the spawning `queue:work` process, but the timeout setting didn't. The process takes about 2-3 minutes to parse the excel file and input it into database, and so it kept timing out after 60 seconds. Can anyone help?

Comment: try ./artisan queue:listen --timeout=0 and see if it is unlimited?

Comment: You are using DB for queuing?

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya it became unlimited, but the process didn't do what it supposed to do while running (the process should've updated a table in DB periodically while running)

Comment: @MinaAbadir yes i'm using the database driver

Comment: haven't found out why, but right now my workaround (since it was needed in a hurry) is changing the default timeout in the vendor...